# Dynamically loading SVG React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Trying to dynamically load SVG's but getting a Runtime Error, and not sure what the issue is. Can anyone help out?

**Component:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { IIcon } from './IIcon';
import {
    DEFAULT_ASSET_ICON_FOLDER,
} from '@/constants/default';

function Icon({name}: IIcon) {
  const ImportedIconRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const importIcon = async () => {
      try {
        ImportedIconRef.current = (
          await import(`${DEFAULT_ASSET_ICON_FOLDER}/${name}.svg`)
        ).ReactComponent;
      } catch (err) {
        // @TODO - Log error somewhere
      }
    };
    importIcon();
  }, [name]);

  const SvgIcon = ImportedIconRef.current;

  return (
    <SvgIcon />
  );
}

export default Icon;
```

**Usage:**
I just want to pass in a string based reference to the file name.

```
<Icon name="DELETE" />
```

**Error**
This is the error I'm getting back, referring to Element type is invalid

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Icon`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning an null / undefined `<SvgIcon />` while the svg is being loaded.

1. Add a `loading` state variable & update it in `finally` block.

```
const [, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const importIcon = async () => {
      try {
        ImportedIconRef.current = (
          await import(`./${DEFAULT_ASSET_ICON_FOLDER}/${name}.svg`)
        ).ReactComponent;
      } catch (err) {
        // @TODO - Log error somewhere
        // console.log(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    importIcon();
  }, [name]);
```

2. Add a null check

```
if (SvgIcon) {
    return <SvgIcon />;
  }
return null;
```

[image: Edit practical-kilby-3h7iwn]